# does ring buffer get dumped to disk during a crash

Tags: logging, linux-kernel

I am wondering, in case of a crash, does Linux try to dump the content of its ring buffer (which is used by dmesg) to disk to ease debugging?

If so, how does Linux do it? If somebody could point me to some code, that will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when crash/panic happens the syslog  does not get a chance to run and so there is very less chance that it will write buffer to disk or /var/log/messages. You have to use
kdump to do that for you after the panic.

You can read more on kdump/kexec

http://www.linux-mag.com/id/2998/

https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-kdump.html

https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-kdump-crash-log.html

Comment: Alternatively, one may instruct the system to additionally dump the kernel log messages to a serial console. This allows to retrieve the log even if `syslog` did not have a chance to save it the usual way.